# How to change the default JS Server port in Android Application from 8081 to something else

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-android

On my system another application is using 8081 port. 
I am running below command to start react-native app on 9988

```
react-native start --port 9988
```

However when I run android, app is still listening at 8081 port

```
react-naive run-android
```

I managed to get it running by using adb reverse command for my Physical device

```
adb -s <deviceid> tcp:8081 tcp:9988
```

I have to do this every time when I am running android on my Physical Device. For emulator it is still not working even after using adb reverse.

Is there config which I can change to default 9988 port

Answer (score 2):

Yes, shake your device and edit the development settings. If I remember correctly you must specify the IP followed by the port.

```
127.0.0.1:9988
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Access the in-app developer menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu) – TLDR: `adb shell input keyevent 82`
2. Dev settings > Debug server host & port for device (Under "Debugging" section)
3. Enter `localhost:9988`
4. `react-native run-android --port 9988`